# Stable Diffusion Dreambooth Model pushing to Hub

Tags: stable-diffusion, fine-tuning

I fine-tuned a Stable Diffusion Model with Dreambooth in Colab. Now the new Model with the weights is located here
`/content/my_model/facial-sketch/800`
I also got the `.ckpt` file. How can I now push this model to my the HuggingFace Hub. I tried with the method `push_to_hub("Path")`, but it didn't work. Also couldn't I use the argument `--push_to_hub` during the training.
Are they any solution to push trough the path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HuggingFace's Hub Python Library](https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/guides/upload)

First install it and login:

```
pip install -U huggingface_hub
huggingface-cli login
```

Assuming that the `.ckpt` file is at `/content/my_model/facial-sketch/800.ckpt`
Run the following in a new cell:

```
from huggingface_hub import HfApi
api = HfApi()
api.upload_file(
    path_or_fileobj="/content/my_model/facial-sketch/800.ckpt",
    path_in_repo="model.ckpt",
    repo_id="username/mymodel",
    repo_type="model",
)
```

You can create a model at hf.co/models with your account. Then, change `username/mymodel` for the path of your model. (ex.: `https://huggingface.co/johndoe/yogurt` would be `johndoe/yogurt`)